# WebSocket communication error

Tags: tomcat, tcp, websocket

Trying to understand what is wrong with WebSocket communication since the fact application is trying resend message.

[image]

The last WebSocket packet contains error:

```
The client frame set the reserved bits to [4] for a message with opCode [7] which was not supported by this endpoint
```

WebSocket server runs on Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0):

The client is sending a frame with OpCode 7. That OpCode is not defined by RFC 6455 and does not appear in the [IANA registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xhtml#opcode) so Tomcat does not know how to handle it and therefore closes the connection.

This looks like a broken client to me.